# "In waves" and "until"

Tags: meaning

"You received a message in early April that indicated you would receive a decision regarding your admissions into our program on May 7th, 2020. Due to the overwhelming amount of candidates that have submitted supplemental information we will be releasing decisions **in waves** **until** June 1st, 2020."

Does "in waves" mean all at once or in multiple times? Also, does "until" here mean I should be expecting the decision sometime before June 1st or exactly on the 1st?

Thanks.

Comment: _In waves_ means in multiple releases (think waves breaking on the shore), June 1 being the last one. Your decision will be in one of those releases.

Comment: Although I wouldn't put my faith in an institution that uses 'amount' with countable nouns, and the impersonal 'that' instead of 'who' when referring to people. (-: